# PreparedStatement и defaul value в jdbc Spring

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, preparedstatement

Подскажите, пожалуйста, создаю PreparedStatement c запросом на вставку в PostgreSQL. В таблице есть поле created (с типом TimestampTZ). Выглядит это так (код нерабочий из-за значения DEFAULT во вставке в 7 поле):

```
PreparedStatementCreator preparedStatement = new PreparedStatementCreator() {

        @Override
        public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection con) throws SQLException {
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO posts (parent, author, message, isedited, forum, thread, created) " +
                    "VALUES(?, (SELECT nickname FROM users WHERE LOWER(nickname)=LOWER(?)), ?, ?, " +
                    "(SELECT forum FROM threads WHERE id = ?), ?, ?)");

            ps.setInt(1, post.getParent());
            ps.setString(2, post.getAuthor());
            ps.setString(3, post.getMessage());
            ps.setBoolean(4, post.getIsEdited());
            ps.setString(5, post.getForum());
            ps.setString(6, post.getForum());
            ps.setTimestamp(7, post.getCreated() == null ? DEFAULT : post.getCreated());
            return ps;
        }

    };
```

Вопрос - можно ли как-то реализовать так, чтобы при post.getCreated() == null в запросе на вставку уходила команда DEFAUL, а если не равно, то значение post.getCreated()

Comment: так сейчас это и выполняется

Comment: Нет, тк java не распознает значение DEFAULT. Я вставил его (DEFAULT) туда, чтобы передать смысл функционала, который я хочу реализовать

Comment: @eafomichev Тогда проясните пожалуйста что сейчас работает не так? Если DEFAULT - какая то константа из-за которой происходит ошибка, то добавьте стэктрейст

Comment: DEFAUL - это просто слово, добавленное сюда для понимания, что требуется сделать. Но, видимо, оно наоборот, ввело в заблуждение. Прошу прощения. Необходимо сформировать запрос, который корректно отрабатывал бы при post.getCreated() == null, т.е. чтобы запрос в этом случае был такого вида: "INSERT INTO posts (..., created) VALUES (..., DEFAULT)". В этом случае в СУБД значение DEFAULT вставить дефолтное значение, указанное при создании БД. Собственно, в этом и вопрос, как правильно сформировать PreparedStatement, чтобы когда нужно было, в запросе фигурировало значение DEFAULT

Comment: Если так, то есть ньюанс - jdbc драйвер не имеет реализации для использования ключевого слова DEFAULT вот в подтверждении моих слов ссылка  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25779623/sending-the-default-placeholder-via-jdbc
Лучший способ - вынести значение как enum.